# Chromium flashplayer

Tags: flash, chromium, 18.04

Did anyone manage to get chromium web-browser working with flashplayer ?

So far what I tried:

`sudo apt install flashplugin-installer`

that worked well for firefox but no effect on chromium.

then I tried:

`sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

but it removed the adobe-flashplugin and made firefox's tabs crash when I tried to play some flash powered video. But again no effect to chromium.

I tried both snap and non-snap version.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The only package needed for Chromium is `adobe-flashplugin`. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) provides updated instructions for Ubuntu users.

Comment: Installing `adobe-flashplugin` and `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` fixed it for chromium but made firefox unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/10/pepper-flash-chromium-opera-ubuntu/

After several combinations I found that only following step #1,step #2 and step #4 (avoiding step #3) and installing flashplugin-installer, somehow worked for both.